# Limitations of ScriptManager in AJAX Calls

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, scriptmanager

Is there any limitations on AJAX Calls with ScriptManager to Web Services?

I have an application and I need an AJAX enabled form in it. After every Insert or Delete, I have to get a list from database and show it on page. So I call two server methods from my JS.
Isn't too many AJAX calls gonna cause any errors(eg. timeouts, transfer errors etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many of any kind of request will give you the same things to worry about.  An AJAX request is just like any other HTTP request, a ScriptManager control won't be imposing any constraints.

The only limitation is your hardware and your IIS settings (application pool connections, etc.).

Of course, you should always be smart about how you program your methods, utilize caching where appropriate, etc. to ensure that they will hold up under heavy load.

Comment: tnx.
And is there any difference between Cassini webserver and IIS in handling these ajax calls?
Cause I have to ship a software really fast and I can't test every piece on IIS. Sometimes I get inappropirate timeout messages in my ajax calls. I figured It might be Cassini's problem.

Comment: That doesn't seem very likely to me, although I guess it is possible.  You might want to use Fiddler to track your ajax requests and see what's going on.